# Importing Stack of Images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, import

So I have the code to import a stack of images, but I am getting an error: `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

```
myPath = 'E:\folder name\'; %' 
fileNames = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.tif')); 
width = 1400;
height = 1050;
nbImages = length(fileNames);

C=uint8(zeros(width, height, nbImages)); 

for i=1:length(fileNames)
    C(:,:,i)=imread(cat(2,'E:\folder name\',fileNames(i).name));
    i
end
```

I understand that the error is originating from the `for` loop, but I don't know of any other way to fill in an empty matrix with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images must not be all the same size. You can handle this by using explicit assignment for the first two dimensions. This will zero-pad any images which are smaller than the rest.

```
im = imread(...);
C(1:size(im, 1), 1:size(im, 2), i) = im;
```

Also, there is a good chance that your images have multiple color channels (the third dimension), so you'll likely want to concatenate along the *fourth* dimension rather than the third.

```
C(:,:,:,i) = imread(...)
```

Comment: My images are strictly greyscaled and all have the same dimensions 1400x1050. Also, I am wanting to read multiple (a stack) of images, how will `imread` achieve this?

Comment: Based on your error, they are *not* all the same dimensions. Try loading the first image and checking the size with `size`

Comment: Ah! my dimensions were the wrong way round! my code works just fine, but I will accept your answer for others as an alternative method to import a stack of images.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it all depends what you want to do with the images, but in general, if you want a "stack" of images (or a "stack" of anything, really), then it sounds like you should be collecting them as a [*cell array*](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) instead.
Also, the correct way to create safe filenames is using the [`fullfile`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) command

e.g.

```
C = cell(1, length(nbImages)); 
for i = 1 : length (fileNames)
  C{i} = imread (fullfile ('E:','folder name', fileNames(i).name));
end
```

If you *really* want to concatenate to a 3D matrix from your cell array, assuming you have checked this is possible, you can do this very easily using [comma-separated-list generator](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) syntax:

```
My3DMatrix = cat(3, C{:});
```